# @RequestBody can not read MultiMap

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jackson, multimap

I am trying to use `MultiValueMap` (implementation of `MultiMap`) from apache collections. I am using Spring MVC's `@RequestBody` annotation. However, I keep getting `HTTPMediaTypeNotSupportedException`. When I change the implementation to use `Map` of `Map` from Java Util, it works fine.

Any clue? Is Jackson API unable to work with anything other than core JDK Types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `@RequestBody` parameter is converted using `HttpMessageConverter`. For `MultiValueMap` you should register a custom converter. For more details, check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) and [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion).